# Python output not displaying in html using the reticulate package in R

Tags: python, r, shiny, reticulate

I have a R script code as below and it is working well for R commands for which it shows the output of eval expression in the html file, however when I replace the expression with R command which evaluates the python file it shows the output on the console and not in the html file.

Below is the script which works

```
listfile<-"temp.html"  # Create temp.html file in current directory 
listcon <- file(listfile, "w")
sink(listcon, append = TRUE, type = "output", split = split)
eval(parse(text="print('hello')"))  # Evaluate the expression and shows the output on html file
close(listcon)
```

however, if I only change the eval expression as shown below, it shows the output on the console but not on the html file.

```
listfile<-"temp.html"
listcon <- file(listfile, "w")
sink(listcon, append = TRUE, type = "output", split = split)
eval(parse(text="py_run_file('code.py')")) # This line now shows the output in console but not in the browser
close(listcon)
```

Below is the code in code.py

```
print('Python hello code')
```

My folder structure is as below:

```
|
|- script.R
|- code.py
|- temp.html
```

Thanks for your time and suggestion.